# Application screen (when I press super key) is broken on 21.10

Tags: gnome

I expect it to show list of recent apps and as I type update the list matching my results. Neither happens it's just always blank.

I'm not able to open any app using the GUI, I have to fall back to terminal.

It will work after a restart, but soon breaks once the system has been running for a short time.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you have custom extensions installed, then these will be the cause. Disable them all, make sure they are updated for Gnome 40 and then enable them one by one until the issue reappears. Discard the extension causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I remove all extensions, remove wallpaper, remove and recreate all my home and Gnome 40 still slow when i press Super Key or click in "Applications".

I use Ubuntu 21.10 (update from 20.04)